# How to integrate Dialogflow V2 into my Application?

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es

In my android application, I'm integrating the Dialogflow V2 Agent. There's no specific SDK for Android yet. So I'm using the java client library from Dialogflow. followed the tutorial https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/25.

I've added the dependencies(dialogflow & oauth2) and created a service account in the google-cloud console. Added the credential file into raw folder. followed the tutorial here https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/25. Getting the error as

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class
>   Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in
>   /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

```
  private void createDialogflow() {
        try {
            InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dialogflow_service_credentials);
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
            String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials) credentials).getProjectId();

            SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
            SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
            sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            session = SessionName.of(projectId, uuid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void sendMessage(String msg) {
        // Java V2
        setTypingMessage();
        QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(msg).setLanguageCode("en-US")).build();
        new RequestJavaV2Task(mContext, session, sessionsClient, queryInput).execute();

    }

    public void callbackV2(DetectIntentResponse response) {
        removeTyingMessage();
        if (response != null) {
            // process aiResponse here
            String botReply = response.getQueryResult().getFulfillmentText();
            Log.d("botReply", "V2 Bot Reply: " + botReply);
            setBotMessage(botReply);
        } else {
            Log.d("botReply", "Bot Reply: Null");
            setBotMessage("There was some communication issue. Please Try again!");
        }
    }
```

Is there any clear documentations on how to integrate Dialogflow v2 into my android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-chatbot-with-dialogflow-8c0dcc8d8018) you were following was updated. In case anyone is facing this issue, according to the [repo](https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/DialogflowChat):

> Save your CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN in gradle.properties